# Show that $f(x)$ lacks vertical asymptotes when $D_f=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I want to show that the function $f(x) = e^{2x-x^2}$ has no vertical asymptotes. It seems intuitive to me that this is the case, since $D_f=\mathbb{R}$ and the denominator is always defined. How can I show this more formally? Is it enough to say that $D_f = \mathbb{R}$ and that the function is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is enough. For any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, you have $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) \in \mathbb{R}$, so no vertical asymptote may exist.